# MemcacheD causing Web Services to slow down

Tags: c#, web-services, memcached

I have two web services that use MemcacheD to store the results of common database queries. Both services run on three load-balanced web servers, as does MemcacheD, and the performance is good. However, every fortnight one of the web service's CPU usage increases to 20% from its more normal 5%. I've found that if I restart Memcache then this sorts the problem out. This particular web service uses MemCacheD more and stores bigger objects

I don't think the issue is with my web service (famous last words I know) since after re-starting Memcache the CPU and memory usage stabilise and remain so for several days.

I think there might be a problem with Memcache either with my usage of it or the way I set it up. If I had to guess I'd say the problem is 'thrashing' in that my web service is having to wait to get an object from Memcache.

Could it be my version of Memcache is too old ([I got it from here](http://allegiance.chi-town.com/MemCacheDManager.aspx)) or that I'm not giving it enough memory. Each instance is currently allocated 128 MB. Is that too low? Are there any tools I could use to measure Memcache's performance to help?

**Edit**

I have increased the memory allocated to 500MB and found that only one of the instances of Memcache needs to be re-started. This points the problem not being with Memcache but with the way I'm using one particular object in there. I'm hoping to push a fix to this soon. If that makes a difference I'll post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am storing two types of data in MemcacheD: one is pure information similar in nature to 'what is the capital of Switzerland', the other are lists used as in-memory stores. It is the latter that caused the problem. One of the lists was not being cleared and as a result was constantly growing. This is why the re-start appears to work because the list is now empty.

MemcacheD does not automatically remove items that have passed their 'expiry' date. What it will do is remove expired items when it needs to. Therefore this list was never being removed. When MemcacheD stores items it stores them on 'pages'. These pages group together items of a similar size. Therefore there will be one for 16KB items, another for 32KB items and so on. Obviously, with a list that was constantly growing this would also be making MemcacheD work harder than it needed to.